# Netflix eureka and zuul not working with Spring 2.1.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I was using Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE and since i need some new features that are now in the version 2.1.1 i decided to update to that version.
After the update I was not able to start neither service with eureka and zuul. 
Both services are compiled without any errors but the exceptions are thrown when jar is started. 
I get the same error with both Java 8 and Java 11.

I was searching for the solution over but I haven't figured out was is the cause to this.

I have parent pom with the definition of:

```
<spring-boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then two separate services for eureka and zuul.
Eureka service pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Zuul service pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>       

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Eureka error log:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

 ERROR 9576 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and [Ljava.lang.Object; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.lambda$collectClasses$1(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:83) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.LinkedList$LLSpliterator.forEachRemaining(LinkedList.java:1239) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.collectClasses(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.getTypes(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:364) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at com.test.discovery.DiscoveryService.main(DiscoveryService.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
```

Zuul service error log:

```
[main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
[main] DEBUG o.s.b.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers - FailureAnalyzer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer@64db4967 failed
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException not present
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:104)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:86)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:950)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getSuperType(ResolvableType.java:466)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:455)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClass(ResolvableType.java:1037)
at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.getCauseType(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:58)
at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.analyze(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:34)
at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.analyze(FailureAnalyzers.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.reportException(FailureAnalyzers.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:848)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:832)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
at com.test.gateway.ApiGateway.main(ApiGateway.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
... 21 common frames omitted
[main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration$AuditEventRepositoryConfiguration
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:447)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:128)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
at com.test.gateway.ApiGateway.main(ApiGateway.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:583)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:568)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:626)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1737)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:721)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:662)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:195)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:159)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:152)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:140)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:135)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:298)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:289)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:278)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:189)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:160)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668)
... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 52 common frames omitted
[main] DEBUG o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@72209d93, started on Thu Dec 27 14:05:30 CET 2018, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@45be7cd5
[main] WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:583)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:568)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:626)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1737)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:721)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:662)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:598)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:590)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1204)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:905)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:891)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:877)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:826)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
at com.test.gateway.ApiGateway.main(ApiGateway.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668)
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 34 common frames omitted
```

Does anyone have a clue what is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to Update Maven Project and *check on force update*. And also clean your "Project > Clean"

Comment: Using maven 3.6.0 and done clean, no change.

Comment: did you try this? Right click on the project and then go to Maven>Update Project>check force update of snapshots>Ok

Answer (score 4):

Finchley is not compatible with boot 2.1.x. Either downgrade boot to 2.0.x or upgrade Spring Cloud to Greenwich.X (currently Greenwich.RC1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @spencerbob I have added Spring Milestone Repository to maven and put Greenwich.RC1 spring-cloud version and it's working fine. Now I saw https://spring.io/blog/2018/11/21/spring-cloud-greenwich-m3-is-available where you explained this, I'm sorry that i haven't read this earlier. Thanks again :)

Comment: @calapurdito Make sure you're using `RC2` and not `M3` or `R1`

Comment: The following config worked for me under java 11: spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.0.1.RELEASE; spring-cloud-version: Finchley.SR3; spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server version: 2.0.1.RELEASE; spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul: 2.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 4):

Spring Boot 2.1 is not compatible with the Finchley release train. You need to upgrade to the Greenwich release train. Greenwich RC2 was just released

https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/21/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc2-is-now-available

```
<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
```

Comment: Finchley is compatible with Spring Boot 2.0. Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Finchley-Release-Notes

Comment: It's not compatible with 2.1.x.